# Redux saga, making an syncroneus batch of async requests

Tags: redux-saga

I have redux-saga v 0.16.2 without ability of an update to something newer - that would demand rewriting half of this legacy project. Right now I am working on files upload functionality. There is no explicit limit on the number of files that user can upload simoultaneously.
The task is as follows. If user uploads more than a certain amount of files, let's say, 20, we chunk all that load to chunks, 20 files max each. So if user uploads 30 files - we need to chunk it to 2 packs of 20 and 10 - and send those one after another, but the files in each of these packs must be sent simoultaneously.
Well, it is pretty easy with the silmoultaneous part - yield all() works like a charm in that case. But I cannot make one all() call to wait for the previous one to finish. The Code that I have right now is as follows :
  `for(let i=0; i < chunkedImagesArray.length; i +=1 ){ yield all(chunkedImagesArray[i].map(image => spawn(singleImageUpload, image))); }`
In the loop, all the yield all() calls just fire one after another without waiting for the previous one to finish. There is a tradeoff to put yield delay() after yield all() call - but that is not the optimal solution.
I dont know about later versions of redux saga - but in this one yield all() does not return anything at all - and once you called it it seems to be no way to see what is happening inside and on what stage it it's execution..
Any ideas about this problem?
Thanks.

Expect each yield all() to be executed only after the previous one finished it's execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace `spawn` with `fork`.

Basically, `all` should wait for all of its child to be done. But in your case, `spawn` would make your `singleImageUpload` task detached to its parent. So `all` effect will not wait for its child to be done.

Check out [document](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#spawnfn-args) for `spawn`.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < chunkedImagesArray.length; i += 1) {
  yield all(chunkedImagesArray[index].map(image => fork(singleImageUpload, image))
}
```

Comment: tried that - unfortunately only one forked operation fires - and that is it, all others are "halted". For now we settled down with the delay() solution.